# What is a simple solution to editable-by-end-user text replacement placeholders?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, replace

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve: a user can display a custom 4-character title for something on a web site, e.g. `NEWS`.  I want to add support for a way that a user can specify  icons from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) as well.

I was thinking about using brackets, e.g. the user would write `[camera]pic` and that would be translated to `<i class="icon-camera"></i>pic` to be displayed with the proper Font Awesome icon.  However, I would also like to be able to escape the markup, so that (e.g.) `f[[x]` would be printed as `f[x]`, not `f[<i class="icon-x"></i>`.  The text placeholders will never be nested, but they maybe be adjacent (e.g. `[star][star][star][star]`). I struggled to solve this using regular expressions*, and concluded that regular expressions probably aren't the appropriate solution to the problem.

Is there a simple solution to this kind of problem that can be cleanly implemented in Javascript and Ruby?  Alternatively, is there another simple way to represent these kinds of text placeholders that meet my sequential and escapable requirements (e.g. `${camera}pic` instead)?  Or will I have to parse it by hand, one character at a time?

---

* As for the regular expressions I've tried: `\[(\w+)\]` is simple but matches when it shouldn't on `f[[x]`.  `(\A|[^\[])\[(\w+)\]` is passes `f[[x]` but fails for every other placeholder in `[x][y][z]`.

Here are my test cases.  Assuming a simple transform of replacing the placeholder the placeholder text prefixed with a `$`, then:

```
describe '#to_var' do
   it { helper.to_var('abcd').should == 'abcd' }
   it { helper.to_var('[foo][bar][baz]').should == '$foo$bar$baz' }
   it { helper.to_var('[[x]').should == '[x]' }
   it { helper.to_var('<[[x]>').should == '<[x]>' }
   it { helper.to_var('<[x]>').should == '<$x>' }   
end
```

The closest regex I came up with was:

```
 icon_code_regex =  %r(
    (\A # beginning of string
     | # or
     [^\[]) # not a left bracket
    \[ # literal left bracket
    (\w+) # the good stuff
    \] # literal right bracket
  )x

str.gsub(icon_code_regex, '\1$\2').gsub('[[', '[')
```

which fails the `[foo][bar][baz]` case.

Comment: Have you tried look-behind? Can you post a sample text of all the cases (especially escaping)?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Just added my test cases.  Haven't tried look behind, but I can research that tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript solution:

```
var str = 'abcd [foo][bar][baz] [[x] <[[x]> <[x]>';

str = str.replace( /(\[)?\[(\w+)\]/g, function ( match, escaped, icon ) {
    return escaped ? '[' + icon + ']' : '$' + icon;
});

// "abcd $foo$bar$baz [x] <[x]> <$x>"
```

Comment: Similar to Bergi's solution, it is slightly different from a 2 step solution, when it comes to `[[[[x]`, though I am not sure what OP really wants for this case

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution for Ruby

You can use look-behind to prevent the substring `[word]` in `[[word]` from matching:

```
(?<!\[)\[(\w+)\]
```

The look-behind `(?<!\[)` simply checks `[` does not appear before the string we want to match.

[**DEMO**](http://rubular.com/r/otLFwocXHy)

#### Solution for JS

For JS workaround, since it doesn't have look-behind:

```js
// Match one non-opening-bracket character, then the [word],
// but the closing bracket is not consumed, for the case
// of consecutive [word1][word2]
var regex = /(^|[^\[])\[(\w+)(?=\])/g;
var arr;

var output = "";
var lastAppend = 0;

while ((arr = regex.exec(inputString)) !== null) {
    // Append substring from index of lastAppend to right before opening [
    // lastAppend will either be at beginning of the string (0)
    // OR right after closing ] from previous match
    output += inputString.substring(lastAppend, arr.index + arr[1].length);
    output += "$" + arr[2];

    // Need to offset by 1 to skip the closing ] (not consumed)
    lastAppend = regex.lastIndex + 1;
}

output += inputString.substring(lastAppend);
```

It is quite ugly. I am not sure if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Upvoted, but this doesn't work in Javascript because JS doesn't support lookbehind :(  I'm looking in to workarounds though.

Answer (score 2):

Just for demonstration, here is a more elegant JS solution which uses [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var output = str.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, function(match, icon, offset) {
    if (offset>0 && str.charAt(offset-1) == '[') // if previous existed and was [
        return match.slice(1); // return the match but without opening [
    // else
    return '<i class="icon-' + icon + '" />'; // or whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: +1. This one step solution will be slightly different from a 2 step solution, when it comes to `[[[[x]`, though I am not sure what OP really wants for this case.